# android motionLayout's CustomAttribute - how to specifiy a background color from drawable resources

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

IN androids motionLayout i need to change the color while the view transitions. but it seems to not take resource links such as "@drawable/myshape". it wants raw values like "#FFFFFF". here is what i have done so far:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/transition"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        app:motionInterpolator="linear"
        app:moveWhenScrollAtTop="true">

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/spaceShip"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

<!--            <CustomAttribute-->
<!--                app:attributeName="backgroundColor"-->
<!--               app:customColorValue="@drawable/space_spaceShip_bg" />-->
```

//the above code does not work. it wants a raw value, how to specify it from a drawable as  i created a custom background shape already for my background.

```
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/spaceShip"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="backgroundColor"
                app:customColorValue="#FFFFFF" />    //also here how to specify @color/white instead of raw value
        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Comment: I think you could try `app:customColorValue="@color/youColor"` and it will work tested on   `constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta1`

Comment: What about with a gradient shape using shape tag . I built in and it's a drawable res folder. Are you able to reach it?

Comment: this is the supported attributes [https://imgur.com/ugvoK7V](https://imgur.com/ugvoK7V)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems the way to do this is to find a property of some view that has a setter that scales from 0 to 1.  the [imageFilterView][1] class is one such.
it has a property called [setcrossfade][2]

so my motionlayout can look like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        android:id="@+id/transition"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
        app:constraintSetStart="@id/start">

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/myview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:alpha="1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="crossfade"
                app:customFloatValue="0" />

        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/myview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:alpha="0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

            <CustomAttribute
                app:attributeName="crossfade"
                app:customFloatValue="1" />

        </Constraint>

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

and in our layout file we can do this:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
    android:id="@+id/ml"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/motion_scene">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.utils.widget.ImageFilterView
        android:id="@+id/myview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"

        android:src="@drawable/bg1"
        app:altSrc="@drawable/bg2"

        android:background="@drawable/bg1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

transition it how you want ..manually or using a swipe in the motion layout file.  anyway afterwards, it will fade out one drawable and fade in another one. exactly what i wanted.
[1]: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/utils/widget/ImageFilterView
[2]: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/utils/widget/ImageFilterView#setCrossfade(float)